# Не работает метод .pop() у массива JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

У меня есть глобальный массив:

```
let folders_history = [];
```

Он пополняется методом .push() в функции, которая вызывается при клике на кнопку.

При клике на другую кнопку вызывается другая функция, которая должна удалить последний элемент массива

```
folders_history.pop();
```

Но этого не происходит. Из массива не удаляется последний элемент. При этом ошибок в консоли нет.

```js
let folders_history = ['a\a', 'b\b', 'c\c'];
let goBack = function() {
  folders_history.pop();
  console.log(folders_history);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">back</button>
```

Comment: `let a = [{}]; a.pop(); console.log(a);` Все работает!

Comment: Вы удаляете последний элемент не из того массива, который потом проверяете.

Comment: У меня все так же, Kir_Antipov, проверяю тот же массив Igor, ничего не получается. Элемент к массиву добавляется методом .push(), но удалить последний элемент никак не получается.

Comment: html:
`<button onclick="goBack()">back</button>`
js:
`let folders_history = [];`
`let goBack = function(){
 folders_history.pop();
 console.log(folders_history);
}`

Comment: - Что это такое?

Comment: Очень страно....... Ваш код работает. Мой нет. Наверное - это проклятие

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, ахах, улыбнуло

Comment: @Igor, В массив добавляются строки, содержащие \
Может это как то повлиять?

Comment: а сам метод вызывается? console.log отрабатывает?

Comment: @Daniel, Да, клик по кнопке срабатывает

Comment: "Но этого не происходит." - чего не происходит?

Comment: @Igor, метод .pop(), последний элемент не удаляется. Массив остается таким же каким был.

Comment: @Илья Как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor все я разобрался. При удалении элемента из массива вызывался метод его же добавления обратно другой функцией.

Comment: Закройте пожалуйста вопрос (или поправьте вопрос и укажите на то что, разобрались), чтобы другие пользователи могли понять что вопрос решен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. При удалении элемента из массива вызывался метод его же добавления.